# Docker image running a Mac OS X installation

Tags: macos, docker, osx-elcapitan

I am using Docker for Mac and wish to create Docker image running a Mac El Capitan with my development env.

I am not finding any resources on this. All I see is Linux installations.

On Linux I saw things as simple as:

```
FROM sciensa2/docker-java8
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget unzip libgtk2.0-0:amd64 libxtst6
```

But what would be the FROM value for OS X to install and run other software?

Comment: Docker for Mac share the same images with Linux Docker, because Docker for Mac actually running a Linux VM on your machine. So what's your concern?

Comment: well i m not concerned about host OS. i need the final image virutalizing a mac osx rather linux

Comment: So are you trying to run a MacOS env in a Docker container?

Comment: There is an ongoing discussion about providing at least some level of MacOS docker support. https://github.com/containerd/containerd/discussions/5525

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you are trying to run Mac OS as the base system in a Docker container, unfortunately there is no way to do it.

Docker container need to use the host machine's Linux Kernel, since Mac OS family is Unix-based operating system, currently Docker cannot simulate a Mac OS in Docker container. Here is [a link to explain how container works](https://docs.docker.com/engine/understanding-docker/#/how-does-a-container-work).

Comment: by base system, I think you mean "host"

Comment: I don't think this answer is very accurate or complete. On a MacOS host, I can build an Ubuntu image and run an Ubuntu docker container. So why not the reverse?

Comment: @AlexanderMills base system is different from "host". Base system has been called "base image" by Docker officially, which is the first layer of an docker image and has been specified with "FORM" annotation in a dockerfile. Doc here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from

Comment: @AlexanderMills On a MacOS host, ubuntu is not really running on this MacOS environment, but running on a docker engine in a Linux VM. You are actually building Ubuntu image on a Linux VM.

Comment: But what about microsoft windows? It can run from within a docker container?

Comment: @LennartRolland No it can't. The same reason with MacOS, Docker container needs a Linux Kernel but windows doesn't have it.

Comment: @LennartRolland yes, Microsoft has enabled Windows containers, although they must run on a Windows host that uses the same version of the OS https://www.docker.com/products/windows-containers. That's a great start, and hopefully Apple will do the same one day.

Comment: @abd3721 It's now also possible to run Windows docker images from a macOS host ([ref](https://github.com/StefanScherer/windows-docker-machine)).

Comment: This should no longer be the accepted answer, see @birnbaum's answer.

Answer (score 29):

This would be nice, particularly for CI servers:

1. You can run [OSX on QEMU](https://github.com/kholia/OSX-KVM) (akin to VirtualBox, emulates the
   kernel).
2. You canrun [QEMU from a Docker](https://matchboxdorry.gitbooks.io/matchboxblog/content/blogs/build_and_run_arm_images.html) container. I have
   done this for ARM dev and it works well.
3. So yes, you can run OSX
   from Docker, but you have to emulate, use a virtual
   machine in the container.

Answer (score 18):

If hardware virtualization ([KVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine)) is available on your host, you can now use [Docker-OSX](https://github.com/sickcodes/Docker-OSX) to run/emulate macOS on QEMU/KVM via [OSX-KVM](https://github.com/kholia/OSX-KVM).

Answer (score 5):

The future is now!

Run Mac OS X in Docker with near-native performance. https://github.com/sickcodes/Docker-OSX