# How to build react native iOS app with docker?

Tags: ios, docker, react-native

I want to build my react native iOS app using docker, My problem is that when I run `react-native run-ios` I'm getting an error that it cant find the simulator. I know the issue occur because I don't have Xcode on my docker.

I was looking for image for Mac or Xcode but all found is a few images for old versions of Xcode and they are not working anymore, I couldn't find images for Mac or any other way to install Xcode on my docker or install iOS simulator on image that isn't Mac OS.

Im attaching my docker:

```
FROM openjdk:8 as builder
ENV SDK_URL "https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip"
ENV ANDROID_HOME /usr/src/app
ENV ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION 28.0.3
ENV ANDROID_VERSION 28
ENV PATH $PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/bin
ARG NODE_VERSION=12.x
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./

# installing android and java
RUN apt update -qq && apt install -qq -y --no-install-recommends \
       apt-transport-https \
       curl \
       build-essential \
       file \
       git \
       openjdk-8-jre \
       gnupg2 \
       python \
       ruby-full \
       openssh-client \
       zip \
       unzip \
   && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*/;  


RUN npm i -g react-native-cli
#installing libraries
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN react-native run-ios;
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: someone with an answer?

Answer (score 3):

This can't be done right now. The reason being that only macOS systems can develop native iOS apps; therefore, react native doesn't support iOS development on anything but a Mac. Docker containers are all built on Linux, not macOS, so this is currently unfeasible, unfortunately. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40824547/docker-image-running-a-mac-os-x-installation).